# What bluetooth services does a switch need to be detected by apple switch control

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth, switchcontrol

What services does a bluetooth enabled device need to have to be recognised by and used with apple switch control?

We are creating a bluetooth enabled devices (4.0) and we need to know how to get the devices detected by apple's switch control for both mac os and iOS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Any device that sends a key or mouse click event should qualify, though some keys cannot be bound to switches.